# How can I hide an element when a user selects an option, navigates away, or selects the same option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm practicing some JQuery and am working on a simple app that asks the user what their favorite food and drink are.

I'm trying to create the app so that the resulting text... "Your favorite food is x, and drink is y", only shows when the user has actually selected their favorite food/drink and when they aren't actively selecting.

My problem is, I can't figure out how to hide the resulting text while the user is selecting the options, in a manner that also has the ability to show the text once the selects are made. I used a change() method which allows me to show the text when they select something new. But what about if the user clicks away, or selects the same option?

Thoughts?

Here's the code...

http://codepen.io/zharriott/pen/oZxvBO?editors=1011

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  /******************
  REFERENCES
  ******************/
  const $foodSelector = $('.questions__q1'),
      $drinkSelector = $('.questions__q2'),
      $dropdownInputs = $('.questions select'),
      $foodResultTxt = $('.result__fav-food'),
      $drinkResultTxt = $('.result__fav-drink'),
      $result = $('.result'),
      $resultTxt = $result.text();

  /******************/
  $dropdownInputs.change(() => {
    //IF food/drink has not been selected, leave result hidden
    if ( $foodSelector.find(':selected').text() === 'Select an option...' || $drinkSelector.find(':selected').text() === 'Select an option...' ) {} 
    else {
      //Update and show result to display user's current answers
      $foodResultTxt.text($foodSelector.find(':selected').text());
      $drinkResultTxt.text($drinkSelector.find(':selected').text());
      console.log($resultTxt);
      $result.show(1400);
    }
  });
});
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Try using the `focus` and `blur` events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider saving the current value of the input with the `focus` event and then comparing the selected value after `change` with both the previous one and the placeholder.

```
$dropdownInputs.focus(function(){
    var oldFoodValue = $foodSelector.find(':selected').text();
    var oldDrinkValue = $drinkSelector.find(':selected').text();
}).change(() => {
    //IF food/drink has not been selected or is equal to the previous value, leave result hidden
    if ( $foodSelector.find(':selected').text() === 'Select an option...' ||
         $drinkSelector.find(':selected').text() === 'Select an option...' ||
         $foodSelector.find(':selected').text() === oldFoodValue ||
         $drinkSelector.find(':selected').text() === oldDrinkValue) {} 
    else {
      //Update and show result to display user's current answers
      $foodResultTxt.text($foodSelector.find(':selected').text());
      $drinkResultTxt.text($drinkSelector.find(':selected').text());
      console.log($resultTxt);
      $result.show(1400);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Edited so that it registers the initial value for both the inputs and takes them both into account when something changes

Comment: This is a great idea, and I think combined with another idea I just had it may work. I'm going to record the value of the selection when the user focuses on the select, and then within a click handler for the select element have a click handler for the entire document. If the user clicks anywhere within the document (including another answer) then I'll check if the answers should be updated and shown... do you forsee any issues with this solution? Thanks for the help btw!

Answer (score -1):

```
$foodResultTxt.hide();
```

and when need to show:

```
$foodResultTxt.show();
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, though the -1 wasn't me. I still appreciate the attempt lol